# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova OneSignal Ionic v1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, onesignal

I'm trying to integrate OneSignal into my Ionic v1 project. I've installed the plugin, referenced the OneSignal.js file in my index.html, and added this to my app.js:

```
var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
        console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
      };

      window.plugins.OneSignal
        .startInit("MY_APP_ID")
        .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
        .endInit();
```

I've also tried adding this wrapper:

```
if(window.plugin != undefined){
    var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
        console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
      };


      window.plugins.OneSignal
        .startInit("MY_APP_ID")
        .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
        .endInit();
}
```

The error disappears, but the push notification isn't working when I build and run on my device in iOS.

Any suggestions as to how to get OneSignal integrated into my Ionic v1 app?

Comment: just one suggestion always use `===` while you are checking any condition in js

Comment: Thanks @Edison. Unfortunately, that didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to include it in index.html file use this code inside of  $ionicPlatform.ready function

```
 var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
   //your code here
      };
  window.plugins.OneSignal
   .startInit("0000-000")
   .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
   .endInit();
```